# IP address for ingress controller on bare metal

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubernetes-ingress

I have a cluster with two nodes. I want to publish some services to internet. So I need to pin my domains to some address. Basically I understand, that I need to install ingress controller. But, am I right I need to glue ingress controller to the particular node?

Comment: Exposing your Ingress controller (for example: nginx) can differ a lot basing on your setup. Things like is it a cluster provisioned internally, is it a cloud solution (like GKE or AKS), do you have metallb installed, do you have any firewall in between. To give you the exact solution, more information about your setup will be needed :).

Comment: Thanks for clarification questions. So, I have manually installed k3s cluster on two nodes. No AWS or any cloud balancers. I don’t know a lot about metalib, and I have not installed it yet. But, looks like metalib it’s what I need.

Comment: checkout the documentation from nginx [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/). The easy way would be to assign your ingress pod to a node [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) and then use nodeport to expose your ingress to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Ingress controller helps to manage the ingress resources in the cluster. So along with the controller you need to create the ingress resources which will be the "glue" between the domain and the services(target application).

Please read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for more.

One sample from the documentation:

foo.bar.com/bar -> service1

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-wildcard-host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "foo.bar.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/bar"
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume in you answer is an example of “ingress resource”. When “ingress controller” is a thing which works like a load balancer.

Comment: yes. the ingress resources are the rules or settings how you want to map the incoming traffic to backend. And the component that implements these resources is the controller.